# How to localize ActiveRecord messages in general?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, localization, internationalization

I'm trying

```
ru:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      format: "%{message}"
```

with no effect, but

```
ru:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      messages:
        record_invalid: "Неверные значения: %{errors}"
```

is working. I want to override both.

My Rails is 3.2.1 on the top of Ruby 1.9.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this localization code

```
ru:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      messages:
        taken: "%{model} с таким именем уже существует"
        record_invalid: "Валидация не прошла: %{errors}"
        restrict_dependent_destroy:
          one: "Невозможно удалить запись, так как существуют зависимости: %{record}"
          many: "Невозможно удалить записи, так как существуют зависимости: %{record} "
        inclusion: "недопустимое значение"
        exclusion: "is reserved"
        invalid: "содержит недопустимое значение"
        confirmation: "doesn't match confirmation"
        accepted: "must be accepted"
        empty: "не может быть пустым"
        blank: "не может быть пустым"
        too_long: "слишком длинно (максимум: %{count} символов)"
        too_short: "слишком коротко (минимум: %{count} символов)"
        wrong_length: "is the wrong length (should be {{count}} characters)"
        taken: "%{attribute} уже занята"
        not_a_number: "может содержать только цифры"
        greater_than: "должно быть больше {{count}}"
        greater_than_or_equal_to: "должно быть больше или равно {{count}}"
        equal_to: "должно быть равно {{count}}"
        less_than: "должно быть меншье {{count}}"
        less_than_or_equal_to: "должно быть меньше или равно {{count}}"
        odd: "может быть только нечетным"
        even: "может быть только четным"
```

Take a look at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/3734521) for more info.

Comment: The thing you suggested makes error messages like: "Пароль слишком коротко" or "Имя учётной записи слишком короток".

Comment: It's a pity but you can't consider all language properties. Just try to rebuild sentence to make it right.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it would be better to use the localisation from this official source: https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/ru.yml